# Why is the if-statement not behaving as expected inside the Javascript forEach iterator?

Tags: javascript, foreach, iteration

I am working on building a maze using recursive division. To start, I'm surrounding the grid with walls. However, there are two openings for the start and end of the maze so those grid nodes should not be converted into a maze wall. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
function createOuterWalls() {
  const wallNodes = [];
  const grid = [{isStart: true, isFinish: false, row: 0, col: 0},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 0, col: 1},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 0, col: 2}
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 1, col: 0},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 1, col: 1},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 2, col: 0},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 2, col: 1}
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: true, row: 2, col: 2}]

  grid.forEach((node) => {
    if (!node.isStart || !node.isFinish) {
      const { row, col } = node;
      if (
        row === 0 ||
        col === 0 ||
        row === 2 ||
        col === 2
      ) 
        wallNodes.push(node);    
    }
  })
  console.log(wallNodes);
}
```

The `WallNodes` will be logged to the console and this is what it will show:

```
wallNodes = [{isStart: true, isFinish: false, row: 0, col: 0},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 0, col: 1},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 0, col: 2}
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 1, col: 0},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 2, col: 0},
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: false, row: 2, col: 1}
                    {isStart: false, isFinish: true, row: 2, col: 2}]
```

All the nodes will be logged except for the middle node, including the start and finish nodes. My question is why is that the case when in my forEach iteration I specify in the if-statement to only include nodes that are neither the start or the finish node (`if (!node.isStart || !node.isFinish)`)?

Comment: How about `!(node.isStart || node.isFinish)`?

Comment: Each item has either isStart=false or isFinish=false, so `if (!node.isStart || !node.isFinish)` will always return true. It might be helpful to log those through each iteration, as well as logging the entire expression to see what it's being evaluated to.

Comment: the start is not the finish and the finish is not the start so it is always going to be true. You want if (not start AND not finish) then do this.

Comment: `!a || !b` is the same as `!(a && b)`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws You wanted `!a && !b` or `!(a || b)`

Comment: You guys are all correct. Thanks a ton! I've been coding for hours and I think my brain was just fried. I appreciate the help!